# Summing across selected columns (using select() methods) in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, contains, rowwise

Summing across columns by listing their names is fairly simple:

`iris %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sum = sum(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length))`

However, say there are a lot more columns, and you are interested in extracting all columns containing "Sepal" without manually listing them out. Specifically, I'm looking for a method in the same way select() in dplyr allows you to subset columns with with contains(), starts_with(), etc.

There are ways to use mutate_all() + sum() + join() in order to fulfill the same result as this query, but I am more interested in seeing something as close to the solution as the code below:

`iris %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sum = sum(contains(colnames(.), "Sepal")))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, basically you're trying to do:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., contains("Sepal"))))
```

First few rows:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species sum
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 8.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 7.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 7.9
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 7.7
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 8.6
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 9.3
```